# React Redux wont identify prop change if the property change happen in nested objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I have a **card** object in my store and it consist of an array of **categories**, inside the categories there is another array of of objects called **barriers**. From the front-end i update a barrier and the change is done in the store. But the change is not reflected in the view/rendering. Here is the structure of the object that needs to be updated.

```
 Card:{
     categories:[{id:12121,
                  name:"exam",
                  barriers:[{
                          id:232343,
                          name:"sit",
                          status:{name:"doing", color:"green",id:32323}
                         }
                  ,{},{}]
                 },{},{}]
        }
```

How can i get this to render in the view. i know one method is to normalize my data structure. But is there any other way to get this done?.

Comment: How we can answer "How can I get this to render in the view" without any "view" code?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [object assign documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Section Examples -> Warning for Deep Clone. I think that your reducer return object is === as state object so react can't detect change. Try json.parse(json.stringify) workaround or use [immutable-js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/). Check and debug **MapStateToProps** function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're passing object reference where you have to pass a new cloned object.
I always use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) module to ensure I am passing a new object down the new state. But there are many choises, like [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) by lodash or simply manually Object.assign() every single object on your state tree.